How do you change one A4 (portrait) page in rmarkdown-pandoc to A3 (landscape) without inserting a separately generated document?
I have a large table that I need to fit in a PDF LaTEX document that is generated ("Knitted") using rmarkdown (specifically bookdown and pandoc, within rstudio) and I think it can only fit on a landscape A3 page.
I have seen potential solutions that required a separately generated PDF page be inserted, but I would like the solution to be self-contained to the rmarkdown document.
I would also like to keep the rest of the PDF document at an A4 size (I do have some other pages that are landscape, but they are also A4).
Can provide additional details on request,
Appreciate any ideas - thanks!
EDIT: Header and output information added below as requested.
title: "Title"
subtitle: "Subtitle"      
author: "NAME"
date: "DATE"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    highlight: haddock
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    keep_tex: true
    toc_depth: 4
geometry: "left=1.6cm,right=1.6cm,top=1.6cm,bottom=3.2cm"


Please add a [mre] so we can see your header, which output option you use etc.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz done, thanks.

The missing space in your header causes a parsing error: Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) :    Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2, column 9 Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> <Anonymous> Execution halted

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, fixed, cheers. Just a heads up though, I am not trying to have someone assess my header or anything else I have done as I haven't got the idea on how to do what i've asked. I am asking for the ideas and potential solutions.

The purpose of posting a [mre] is to get the users willing to help you started so that they don't have to first figure out how a markdown document might look like before they can even start working on a solution for you. Having to first debug your header is annoying. You could avoid this by testing the code before you post it!

Apologies on the code snippet, it was copied directly from a working document, but the space was removed during this copy-paste step.

You could use the typearea package:
---
title: "Title"
subtitle: "Subtitle"      
author: "NAME"
date: "DATE"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    highlight: haddock
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    keep_tex: true
    toc_depth: 4
geometry: "left=1.6cm,right=1.6cm,top=1.6cm,bottom=3.2cm"
header-includes:
 - \usepackage[paper=A4]{typearea}
---

test

\KOMAoptions{paper=A3}
\recalctypearea

something

\KOMAoptions{paper=A4}
\recalctypearea

else



Cheers @sam, i'll give this a shot and report back.

any idea on how to reduce the margins for the A3 page - it seems in the above example, the text is being displayed as if it was still A4?

You could for example use the DVI option: \usepackage[paper=A4,DIV=15]{typearea}. For more information about changing the margins, see the koma script documentation.
